# how to get a mean of a "value" column split into groups based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take a simple dataframe, sum a column ("value" column) into groups - based on the value in another column ("name" column). After that, I want to get a mean of that "value" column

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: df = pandas.DataFrame(data = [{'name': 'a', 'val': 1}, {'name': 'b', 'val': 2}, {'name': 'b', 'val': 4}])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  name  val
0    a    1
1    b    2
2    b    4

In [4]: # What I want:

In [5]: pandas.DataFrame(data = [{'name': 'a', 'mean': 1},  {'name': 'b', 'mean': 3}])
Out[5]: 
  name  mean
0    a     1
1    b     3

In [6]: # Or, better yet:

In [7]: pandas.DataFrame(data = [{'name': 'a', 'sum': 1, '#': 1, 'mean': 1},  {'name': 'b', 'sum': 6, '#': 2, 'mean': 3}])
Out[7]: 
  name  sum  #  mean
0    a    1  1     1
1    b    6  2     3
```

Comment: Try, `df['mean']=df.groupby('name')['val].mean()`

Comment: @AkshaySehgal - returns NAN (and you're missing a ' after val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first only aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['val'].mean()
print (df1)
  name  val
0    a    1
1    b    3
```

For second aggregate `sum` and `mean` in names aggregation by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and it need new column with counter in second position add [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg(sum = ('val','sum'), mean = ('val','mean'))
df2.insert(2, '#', df2.index + 1)
print (df2)
  name  sum  #  mean
0    a    1  1     1
1    b    6  2     3
```

EDIT: For count is used [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html)

```
df3 = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg(s = ('val','sum'), 
                                             no = ('val','size'), 
                                             m = ('val','mean'))
print (df3)
  name  s  no  m
0    a  1   1  1
1    b  6   2  3
```